# why is script not working after setting and declaring parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the following code without setting any parameters I get the desired output

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [CaseNumber]
          ,[EventCode]
          ,[EventDate]
          ,[Assigned]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                    PARTITION BY CaseNumber
                                    ORDER BY CaseNumber,EventDate DESC,EventCode  
                            ) AS [ROW NUMBER] 
      FROM  [databasename].[dbo].[tblCsCaseEvents] 
      ) groups

    WHERE 1=1 
    AND (groups.[ROW NUMBER]=1) AND (Assigned IN ('PARKERE')) 
    AND  EventCode LIKE 'ba%'
```

However, when I declare and set variables as shown below and run it. The script  doesn't seem to work. Why is that the case?

```
Declare @attorney CHAR (10)
Declare @event CHAR (10)

set @attorney='PARKERE'
set @event='ba%'

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [CaseNumber]
      ,[EventCode]
      ,[EventDate]
      ,[Assigned]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                PARTITION BY CaseNumber
                                ORDER BY CaseNumber,EventDate DESC,EventCode  
                        ) AS [ROW NUMBER] 
  FROM  [databasename].[dbo].[tblCsCaseEvents] 
  ) groups

WHERE 1=1 
AND (groups.[ROW NUMBER]=1) AND (Assigned IN (@attorney)) 
AND  EventCode LIKE @event
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char(<n>)` defines a string of exactly a length `<n>`.  If the string is too short, it is padded with spaces.

This affects some comparisons, such as `like`.  Instead, use `varchar()`.

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces) is an explanation from Microsoft.